# select in procedure with loop return only 1 resullt php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$run = $dbh->prepare($query);

echo $query;
//if($run->execute()) {

     if($run->rowCount() > 0) {

         $result = $run->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $i = 0;
         while($i < count($result)) {

             for($e=0; $e < count($result); $e++) {

                 $result[$e] = str_replace('&Ntilde;','Ñ', str_replace('&ntilde;','ñ', $result[$e]));
                  $i++;
             }                    
         }
         return $result;
     } else {
           return array('error'=> TRUE, 'message'=> 'No result found.','query'=> $query);
     }
//}
```

I have this query and the echo in the query is :

```
CALL `select_date`('2016-01-01', '2016-01-31')
```

Where `select_date` is :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `select_date`(

param1 varchar(64),
param2 varchar(64)

)
BEGIN


declare v_max int default 0;
declare v_counter int default 0;
  start transaction;
  set v_max = (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM transaction_detail4
  WHERE 
    transaction_date >= param1 AND 
    transaction_date <= param2);



  while v_counter < v_max do
    # random query
SELECT *
  FROM transaction_detail4
  WHERE 
    transaction_date >= param1 AND 
    transaction_date <= param2 GROUP BY transaction_id LIMIT v_counter , 1000;

    set v_counter = v_counter + 1000;
  end while;
  commit;



END
```

I am assuming that it will loop and return all the data from the loop but it only gives me `1000` meaning only gets first iteration. Because the select should return 49k+ records.

How to return all the data from loop select

Comment: Basically the same as PHP pagination work. You request an x amount of items, starting at point y. So for example if you have 1000 items, but can only get 100 items at the time: the first query will get the first 100 items form those 1000. Second query will get another 100, but starting at row 101, etc. Do you know what I mean? These 10 queries to get all 1000 items can be merged so you can still have all your records. To get 49k+ items in one query, its perhaps a database restriction.

Comment: Other note I see in your query ', 1000'. Does that mean you request 1000, instead of all of them? You might change that to another number and see what it does.

Comment: because if i select all i get out of memory so i want to select by batch

Comment: So basically you want what I wrote about what I first wrote? For that you need to make a query and see how many records are needed. That will be : `Total rows / 1000 = 49. $i = 1, and in your query to get results you do $i++. merge this array with your current array. Once $i == 49, it should stop the query`. Would this help you?

Comment: when i try this in work bench it queries all i will try to get result again

Comment: Ok, let me know!

Comment: @RonnieOosting after i put the query inside a for loop this is the error i got `"HY000",2014,"Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute."`